# How to do maximum array intersection PHP

Tags: php

## I ask a candidate : What do you like ?

**His answer** is an array **[Math,Physics,Chemistry,IT,Sports]**

I do have a list :

- Software Analyst : [Math,IT,Programing,Stress,Computer]
- Truck drive : [Sports,Driving,Traveling,Exchange]
- Physic-chemistry teacher :[Math,Physics,Chemistry,Teaching]

What is the best way in PHP to get the jobs with the maximum common tags with the user input?

Comment: Pretty Unclear .....

Comment: What are the things, that you don't understand? I tried to be as clear as possible.

Comment: use `array_intersect()` to find the common tags, then compare among the return array values

Comment: Added more detail as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `array_intersect()` to find the common tags, then compare among the returned tags amount.

```
$jobs = array(
 'software' => array('Math','IT','Programing','Stress','Computer')
 'truck' => array('Sports','Driving','Traveling','Exchange')
 'physic' => array('Math','Physics','Chemistry','Teaching')
);

$user_tags= array('Math','Physics','Chemistry','IT','Sports');
$max_common = 0;
$desired_job = '';

foreach($jobs as $key=>$job) {

 $common = count(array_intersect($job,$user_tags);

 if(max_common < $common) {
    $desired_job = $key;
    $max_common =  $common;
 }

}
```